# MODX Revo: Синтаксис запроса [[!pdoResources? &where, если надо изменить переменную в запросе

Tags: modx, синтаксис, unixtimestamp

Взял заготовку сайта, допиливаю, имея опыт работы с MODX на уровне "сварщик второго разряда".
На данный момент имеется строка

```
[[!pdoResources?
...
&includeTVs=`BasicDate`
&where=`[{"BasicDate:>":[[!currentDate]]},[[!filter]]]`
```

Из отладчика:

```
BasicDate = "2018-10-03 16:45:00"
currentDate = "1539028502"
filter = `{"AND:template:=":4}`
```

Как в данном выражении привести BasicDate к виду UNIX time, чтобы сравнение работало?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел.

```
&where=`[" UNIX_TIMESTAMP(BasicDate) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()", [[!filter]]]`
```